# Como alterar a versão do PHP no Azure

Tags: php, microsoft-azure

Estou usando no Azure o serviço de WebApp PHP. Pelo painel do Azure eu até consigo alterar a versão do PHP.

Porém já está na última que me diz que é 5.6. Nessa contratamos um serviço de scanner para verificar possíveis vulnerabilidades tanto na aplicação como no servidor e de cara mostrou vulnerabilidades por conta da versão do PHP.

Já tentei contato com a Microsoft mas foi meio cômico. Eu tenho duas opções, uma é pagar o suporte para me responderem isso ou perguntar aqui stack overflow.

Fico muito grato se alguém souber de uma alternativa de alteração da versão do php que não seja pelo painel do azure.

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes da mensagem de vulnerabilidade da versão do PHP?

Answer (score 1):

No último release do App Service do Azure foi publicado PHP na versão 7.0. Veja se resolve seu problema.